# How can I get even heat from consumer gas stovetop burners?

Tags: stove, heat, gas

I have a 5 burner modern style gas cooktop (KitchenAid), 4 in standard positions, one big double in the center.

4 of the burners are all the standard circular shaped and seems most of their heat just goes to the outside edge of a circular pot/pan. I've lost a few non-metal accessories getting used to it.

Most professional models use multiple circles or cross shapes that put heat in the center as well as out sides.

Is there method or part to use that would get more heat into the pot bottom?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This would completely depend on the model of the stove, and the parts available for it. (Yes, this is stating the obvious, but I'm not sure what else someone could say.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, its similar to this: [link](http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/-[KCGS550ESS]-407410/KCGS550ESS/)  Seems Kitchaid calls what I am looking for a "Torch" burner.

Comment: So, what exactly are you asking, then?

Comment: When I was looking for stoves I found that many lacked burners small enough for small pans, or at least for more than one at a time. The flames should be completely under the pan.  There are pot skirts which might help a little.

Comment: Not really an answer so a comment.  High end high conductivity pots will help.  Gas is pretty cheap.

Comment: Is this about what is often called a wok ring?

Comment: Pot skirts could restrict oxygen and cause loss of flame.  A reach but possible.

Answer (score 1):

So this may not be exactly what you were looking for, but I purchased one of these cast iron heat diffusers to help "tame" the heat from the cheap-o gas stovetop in my college apartment. You have to take the time to heat it up, but it helps distribute the heat evenly.

[Cast Iron Heat Diffuser on Amazon](http://a.co/0SVImGy)